# undefined method `map'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am trying to parse db-record data in to my haml-template file for filtering purposes.(isotope jquery)

House model

```
def features_to_html_class
  "#{(guests + bedrooms + type + amenities).map(&:name).join(' ')}"
end
```

House index haml view

```
- @houses.each do |house|
  .item{:class => house.features_to_html_class }
```

I get the error message undefined method `map'.  The values from the db are integers (guests/bedrooms) and strings (type / amenities)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting that in the `features_to_html_class`? You might want to check for `nil` arrays. You can do that with `compact` easily.

```
def features_to_html_class
  (guests + bedrooms + type + amenities).compact.map(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

Comment: the data is not nil. When i try compact..i get undefined method 'compact'

Comment: Worth checking each variable, you probably have a nil variable, if ```(guests + bedrooms + type + amenities)``` evaluated to an array, ```compact``` would work.

Comment: Also, you can remove the string part so that you end up with ```(guests + bedrooms + type + amenities).compact.map(&:name).join(' ')``` (answer edited)

Comment: i tried only guests and bedrooms and both integers. When i go to my console the variabele are filed, but i still get the same error message..

Comment: So there you have it, they are integers, not arrays. This would work: ```([guests] + [bedrooms] + [type] + [amenities]).flatten.compact.map(&:name).join(' ')```, although I would recommend inspecting each variable and understanding which /should/ be an array and which /should/ be an integer.